# ROS-Yocto catkin_make toplevel.cmake

Tags: cmake, embedded-linux, yocto, ros, catkin

I am trying to install ROS into an embedded device (imx8m-mini variscite dart) using Yocto. I have added required ROS packages into the Yocto environment and generated a root file system. I have sourced the **setup.bash** script in my bash environment and then when I do "**catkin_make**" I get an error like this,

```
root@imx8mm-var-dart:~/catkin_ws# catkin_make
Base path: /home/root/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/root/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/root/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/root/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/root/catkin_ws/install
```

> **Creating the toplevel cmake file failed:** Could neither find file **"toplevel.cmake"** in any workspace nor relative, checked the following paths:

```
/home/root/catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
```

As a result, the directories  **build, devel, and src** under **catkin_ws** are empty.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved after adding below package into Yocto build.

```
catkin-dev
```

I am leaving the question here in case someone else suffers the same problem.

Comment: I have two questions for you: 1. What yocto image did you use? Was it `ros-image-core`? and 2. How can I add that package in the Yocto build?

Comment: I added the package and now `catkin_init_workspace` works but `catkin_make` shows a different error